# How to call non-static method in another class's static method in java?

Tags: java, methods, static, non-static

I have this method in one of my class

```
@Override
public void liveFlights(int one, int two, int three, int four, int five,
                        int six, int seven, int eight, int nine, int ten, int eleven, int twelve) {
    System.out.println("There is "+counter+" flights at this moment ");

    System.out.println("England to Netherland at 12.00 pm "+one+"is flight number");
    System.out.println("Netherland to England at 12.00 pm "+two+"is flight");
    System.out.println("Turkey to USA at 06.00 pm "+three+"is flight number");
```

and i want to call this non static method in this static method (another class)

```
public static void searchResEntry() throws java.io.IOException  // start of method
{
    // variable declarations
    String Name;
    String Address;
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter your following information for your reservation result:  \n");   // displaying the information to enter for searching a reservation

    System.out.print("  Enter Name  :   "); // displaying message to enter name
    Name = read.nextLine(); // prompt for the name
}
```

any help ??

Comment: Your static method then needs an instance of the class that contains the non-static method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass instance of your class containing non-static methods into static method

```
public static void searchResEntry(YourClass instance) throws java.io.IOException    // start of method
    {
        // variable declarations
        instance.liveFlights(...);
```

or create instance in it:

```
public static void searchResEntry() throws java.io.IOException    // start of method
    {
        // variable declarations
        YourClass instance = new YourClass();
        instance.liveFlights(...);
```

Comment: i forget to add, non-static method is in my abstract class that why instance think dont work. is it depend ?

Comment: Since you cannot instantiate abstract class, there's not sense in implementing non-static (instance) methods in it unless you have some class that `extends` this abstract class. Either declare this method an `abstract` and provide implementation in the class that extends abstract class, OR declare this method as `static`